# Not mapped property is not getting Foreign key value

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my project, I am using Entity Framework Core. I have the below model and there is a **NotMapped** Property that calculates **other foreign property values**.

```
public class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        Id = 0;
        IsActive = true;
        BillDetails = new List<BillDetail>();
        Payments = new List<Payment>();
        BankPayments = new List<BankPayment>();
        DueReconciles = new List<DueReconcile>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SpouseName { get; set; }
    public string NationalId { get; set; }
    public decimal OpeningBalance { get; set; }
    
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public IList<BillDetail> BillDetails { get; set; }
    public IList<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    public IList<BankPayment> BankPayments { get; set; }
    public IList<DueReconcile> DueReconciles { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal CurrentBalance
    {
        get
        {
            var totalBill = BillDetails.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Sum(x => x.Amount);
            var totalPayment = Payments.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Sum(x => x.Amount);
            var totalReconcile = DueReconciles.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Sum(x => x.ReconcileAmount);

            return Math.Round(((OpeningBalance + totalBill) - (totalPayment + totalReconcile)), 2);
        }
    }
}
```

In the NotMapped Property **CurrentBalance** property returns invalid amount. **BillDetail** Property has value but in CurrentBalance property **totalBill** gets 0.

Can anyone give me suggestion.

Here is my Service code:

```
public MemberListResult Lists(int? orgId)
{
    try
    {
        var lists = _memberRepository.Query().AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.OrgId == orgId).ToList();

        if (lists == null || lists.Count <= 0)
        {
            return new MemberListResult(TaskResult.StatusCodes.ERROR)
            {
                Message = "Member lists are not found.",
                Status = TaskResult.StatusCodes.ERROR,
                ErrorNumber = 1
            };
        }

        return new MemberListResult(TaskResult.StatusCodes.SUCCESS)
        {
            Members = lists
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need the include in the Query method? Where in your code try to get CurrentBalance?

Comment: Use `Include` for all collections involved in calculating `CurrentBalance`.